# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2' has no attribute 'depth_to_space'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow1.15

I am trying to run a code, which was written with tensorflow version 1.4.0
I am running my code on google colab which gives in tensorflow version 2.x with it.

To run my code, I am using backward compatibility like:
replacing `import tensorflow as tf` with

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

which works for certain things, but at a point it comes down to this error

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2' has no attribute 'depth_to_space'

[as you can see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wD7G.png)

What I am not able to understand is this method 'depth_to_space' is in both versions of tensorflow 1.x and 2.x , then why is my version of tensorflow not getting it ?
Here's the link to the method in version 1.x: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/nn/depth_to_space

Please help me understand what's the cause of this error.

Thanks,
Pranay

Answer (score 0):

I tried with **Tensorflow 1.15**.Its working fine.
Looks like your Tensorflow version bit old,

Below sample code tested with Tf 1.15 without any error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
x = [[[[1, 2, 3, 4]]]]

tf.nn.depth_to_space(x, 2, data_format='NHWC', name=None)
```